# Check if string contains 2 numbers

Tags: string, lua

```
if PassField.Text:match("%a+%d%d+") or PassField.Text:match("%d%d+%a+") then
    PWValid = true
else
    return 'Error1'
end
```

This is my code so far but it's not too efficent because the string can be like bb1b12 so i would need to detect if the string contains 2 numbers anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Two numbers is "some digits, then some non-digits, then some more digits". You don't need to care about anything else in string. Just use %d compliment - %D - it means exactly opposite of original. Also you probably should use `find` if you only want to test if string is valid or not.

```
str:find("%d+%D+%d+")
```